# Ruby script to create a temporary file for use with greenletters

Tags: files, ruby

I'm using `expect` to test autocompletions in zsh (actually using the Ruby `greenletters` gem, with uses Ruby's `PTY` under the covers, to call `expect`). After digging through the documentation and old archives (this was the final comment that gave me the below code: https://narkive.com/jbOlxniA:5.2481.94) I have this way of easily loading the completion on a 'clean' system:

```
PROMPT='>' zsh -f
fpath+=($PWD/Completion)
autoload -Uz compinit
_compdir=$PWD/Completion compinit -D
```

Now, creating a file manually and loading it this way works *perfectly fine*. But, as soon as I try to load it using the `greenletters` library it doesn't load any completions:

```
>options Completion/
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a SSCCE written in ruby (I'm having trouble creating the same example in a simple `expect` script). You'll need to run `gem install greenletters` to be able to run this script:

```
require 'tempfile'
require 'greenletters'
require 'tmpdir'

@tempdir = Dir.mktmpdir
completions_folder = @tempdir + '/Completion'
FileUtils.mkdir_p(completions_folder)
@completion_script = Tempfile.create('_completion', completions_folder)
@completion_script.write(DATA)
puts @tempdir
@adv = Greenletters::Process.new("PROMPT='>' zsh -f", transcript: $stdout, timeout: 3)
@adv.start!
@adv.wait_for(:output, />/i)
@adv << "cd #{@tempdir}\r"
@adv.wait_for(:output, />/i)
@adv << "fpath+=($PWD/Completion)\r"
@adv.wait_for(:output, />/i)
@adv << "autoload -Uz compinit\r"
@adv.wait_for(:output, />/i)
@adv << "_compdir=$PWD/Completion compinit -D\r"
@adv.wait_for(:output, />/i)
@adv << "options \t"
@adv.wait_for(:output, />/i)

__END__
#compdef _options options
function _options_help {
  _arguments \
    "-h[Show help information]" \
    "--help[Show help information]"
}
function _options_desc {
  _arguments \
    "--test=[desc]" \
    "-h[Show help information]" \
    "--help[Show help information]"
}
function _options {
  local line

  local -a commands
  commands=(
    'desc:use description flag for description'
    'help:Describe available commands or one specific command'
  )

  _arguments \
    "-h[Show help information]" \
    "--help[Show help information]" \
    "1: : _describe 'command' commands" \
    "*::arg:->args"

  case $state in
    args)
      case $line[1] in
        desc)
          _options_desc
        ;;
        help)
          _options_help
        ;;
      esac
    ;;
  esac
}
_options "$@"
```

Does zsh act differently in a PTY than regular loading? Is this something I just don't understand about PTYs in general? Do they all work like this?

Comment: What's the problem? I do see a prompt to complete `desc` or `help`. Then the script times out because it expects a new prompt, not completion offerings.

Comment: You see a prompt with the ruby script??? It tries to complete the file names for me, not the options for the completion.

Comment: I updated the script because I wasn't cd'ing to the temporary directory (whoops), so I'm really not sure how it worked for you at this point.

Comment: I ran the original script in the same directory where I'd created a `Completion` directory to try manually. Maybe a typo somewhere in the script causing something not to be loaded? I don't know ruby so I didn't review the script.

Comment: That won't work. If the completion script exists _before the ruby script runs_ it succeeds. It only fails if the completion script _doesn't exist before starting the ruby script_. I do not really understand why.

Comment: That's why I make a temp directory with a random name in the script. to demonstrate that fact.

Comment: The bug is in your ruby script. It doesn't create the file as expected. Increase the timeout and look at the content of the temp directory: `_completionXXXX` is empty. I guess you need to flush after writing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had checked that the file existed, but not that it actually had stuff in it. I still had the file open for writing, failing to close which would flush and write.

Comment: The zsh test cases include tests of the completion system using zsh's zpty. I don't see that you gain much by doing it from ruby.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about okapi, this is not to test zshs autocompletion. It's to test autocompletion scripts, that could have been generated incorrectly.